# Android GCM console (package/hash) unexpected results

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So I've been working with GCM and I setup all what's needed on [google console](https://console.developers.google.com), I added **one** entry related to my **package name** and my **DEBUG** **SHA-1 certificate FP**, everything was working fine, but then I signed my app with a new keystore in order to publish it, and without adding the new SHA1 certificate of the new keystore I noticed I was successfully able to register and receive notifications.

I was under the impression that only the entries on the console were able to successfully use GCM, so the normal behavior should be that this newly signed app can't use my current GCM configuration.

Can someone please clarify.

Thanks !!

Comment: I believe so too, but I guess there might be some delay for the server apply the new setting?

Comment: I dont think so, the app has been live for months, but I just noticed that normally it shouldn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to save the configuration until and unless you have added the  SHA-1 certificate fingerprint for a particular API_KEY.

If you see the UI for the new developer console there are two edit texts one for package name and other one for the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. So your API_KEY can e used multiple Apps and the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint would be unique to each of them.

Its not possible that an API_KEy can be created without adding the Package name and Debug certificate and if it does Probably what I am guessing is that, it is using the old package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

Comment: No actually, if an API_KEY is created but no Package/FP is associated, there will be no filter and any app can use it, but in my case I specified the Package/FP of my DEBUG key, so the access is restricted to this only keystore, and technically it shouldn't work with my signing certificate seeing that it's not configured in the console. it's all just weird